# return lines containing numbers in a range in a certain column

Tags: text-processing

Task: return lines containing numbers in range from x to y in column z.

Example, selecting lines with numbers in range 140-160 in column 2.

```
1 1    some data 150
2 150  some data 1
3 151  some data 151
4 1000 some data 150
```

should return:

```
2 150 some data 1
3 151 some data 151
```

Open to using grep, awk, or sed. New to Unix. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` like

```
awk '$2 > 140 && $2 < 160' input_file
```

which will compare the second field (`$2`) to the range you want and only print the lines if both those conditions are satisfied.

If your min and max values are stored in variables you can pass them in with `-v` in `awk` like so:

```
min=140
max=160
awk -v lower="$min" -v upper="$max" '$2 > lower && $2 < upper' input_file
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E -e "^[0-9]+ 1[45][0-9]" -e "^[0-9]+ 160"
```