# return lines containing numbers in a range in a certain column but only if a column contains a certain number

Tags: text-processing, awk

Related to this question...
return lines containing numbers in a range in a certain column
[return lines containing numbers in a range in a certain column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324337/return-lines-containing-numbers-in-a-range-in-a-certain-column)

I know how to delete lines which contain numbers in a certain range. Then how to do if I want to delete lines only when the other column contains a number?

For example, I want to delete lines if the second column contains 4, and the third column contains numbers between 50 to 85?
input

```
a 3 44 563
d 4 55 11 
e 2 93 445
r 4 82 44
e 4 93 33
```

output

```
a 3 44 563
e 2 93 445
e 4 93 33
```

I think we can do something like this... but this does not work.

```
awk '$2==4' & awk '$2 > 85 && $2 < 50' input > output
```

Can anybody know this? Of note, the second column contains only the integers from 1-22.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This awk condition will print those lines:

```
awk '$2 != 4 || $3 > 85 || $3 < 50' input
```

It prints a line when the second column does not equal 4, or the third column is greater than 85, or the third column is less than 50.

This logical equivalent should have the same effect:

```
awk '! ($2 == 4 && $3 <= 85 && $3 >= 50)' input
```

As noted in comments, a clearer way to write the range  comparisons for `min <= num <= max` would be `min <= num && num <= max`. So that would be:

```
awk '! ($2 == 4 && 50 <= $3 && $3 <= 85)' input
```

```
awk '$2 != 4 || $3 < 50 || 85 < $3' input
```

Comment: The common way to write the test for a number in a range is to put the number in the middle with  the min value on the left and the max on the right, e.g.  `min <= num && num <= max`, so the layout of your code clearly reflects it's purpose. You CAN obviously write it a bunch of other ways (e.g. as you have `num <= max && num >= min`) but that way is the clearest to read and hardest to write incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton! Should the same apply when testing for a number outside of a range: `min > num || num > max`?

Comment: That's not quite as obvious but `num < min || max < num` is the syntax that demonstrates that you're testing for `num` outside of a range as it literally has the word `num` on the outsides of the condition. So, to test for `num` inside a range you'd write `min num num max` and to test for `num` outside a range you'd write `num min max num` - the word "num" goes wherever it needs to be relative to the words "min"and "max".

Comment: I always put the variable on the left hand side when comparing. Find it much easier to read. For *me* this for example: `var > min && var < max` reads as if `var` is greater then then *min* and `var` is less then *max*.